# How to cache html file like browser but on server depending on header file

Tags: java

Is there a special function that does this or does one needs to parse the header ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, neither Sun's HttpUrlConnection or the Apache HttpClient stack implement client-side request / result caching.  You'll need to implement this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how industrial purposes are you could cache your response (object) using an embedded cache server like [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/), from which you could "key" on the URL requested.

This may be overkill for your solution it is dependant on weather the cacheing is a nice-to-have or will be an integral part of the solution.

Comment: Yes it is overkilled for what I have now in mind but may be usefull for some other projects of mine so thanks :)